# Get value from RemoteMessage from FCM onMessageReceived method

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have migrate `gcm to fcm` for push notification message.
but how I Get bundle data from RemoteMessage received onMesssageReceived method.

```
Old GCM give bundle data onMessageReceiced method but in FCM there is RemoteMessage data.
```

So please tell me how I parse remotemessage for get all value of notification.

MY PAYROL

```
{
"collapse_key":"score_update",
"priority":"high",
"content_available":true,
"time_to_live":108,
"delay_while_idle":true,
"data": 
{ 
    "message": "Message for new task",
    "time": "6/27/2016 5:24:28 PM"
},
"notification": {
    "sound": "simpleSound.wav",
    "badge": "6",
    "title": "Test app",
    "icon": "myicon",
    "body": "hello 6 app",
    "notification_id" : "1140",
    "notification_type" : 1,
    "notification_message" : "TEST MESSAGE",
    "notification_title" : "APP"
  },
"registration_ids": ["cRz9SJ-gGuo:APA91bFJPX7_d07AR7zY6m9khQro81GmSX-7iXPUaHqqcOT0xNTVsOZ4M1aPtoVloLNq71-aWrMCpIDmX4NhMeDIc08txi6Vc1mht56MItuVDdA4VWrnN2iDwCE8k69-V8eUVeK5ISer"
]
}
```

Comment: This link might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56231468/7254873

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In FCM you received RemoteMessage instead of Bundle.

Below is the way I used in my application where data is my RemoteMessage

```
Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData()
int questionId = Integer.parseInt(data.get("questionId").toString());
String questionTitle = data.get("questionTitle").toString();
String userDisplayName = data.get("userDisplayName").toString();
String commentText = data.get("latestComment").toString();
```

Below is my notification data which I am sending it from server

```
{
  "registration_ids": "",
  "data": {
    "questionId": 1,
    "userDisplayName": "Test",
    "questionTitle": "Test",
    "latestComment": "Test"
  }
}
```

So you have to parse each and every field as per your response. 
As I have debugged the code you will receive map in your RemoteMessage and cast those fields in appropriate data types as all those data comes as string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but My other data under notification object not in data object then how can I get it

Comment: As you have already mentioned in comment that you will get your result from remoteMessage.getNotification(). Can you try that..

Comment: there is no message.get function

Comment: get method is of map. You need to call RemoteMessage.getData() first.

Comment: And don't forget to call toString() method on remoteMessage.getData.get().

Comment: I actually don't have the get method. I have remoteMessage.zzds and in there there is an ArrayMap with the actual values. Any idea how to get it from there?

Comment: @f.trajkovski you can get it with the help of remoteMessage.getData() method, Which actually returns Map<String, String>

Comment: I wasn't able to get the data like that but my issue was on the server side. I was sending the message in a wrong format and that is the reason why I had empty map.

Comment: @DrupDesai How can we use the getData() while using the notification keyword behalf of data. if I am going to use getData then not getting data if the application in kill from background also.

Answer (score 46):

Here is the code snippet which is pretty much self Explanatory.

You get the data in the form of the Map

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
        {
            Log.e("dataChat",remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            try
            {
                Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(params);
                Log.e("JSON_OBJECT", object.toString());
          }
       }
```

Make Sure from server you are sending data in correct format i.e. in the "data" key

here is the demo Json file

```
{
  "to": "registration_ids",
  "data": {
    "key": "value",
    "key": "value",
    "key": "value",
    "key": "value"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but My other data under notification object not in data object then how can I get it.

Comment: `remoteMessage.getData()` returns blank array

Answer (score 2):

For your data that looks like:

```
"data":{ 
    "message": "Message for new task",
    "time": "6/27/2016 5:24:28 PM"
}
```

you should get them through

```
Log.d(TAG, "Key Data : " +  remoteMessage.getData().get("message").toString());
Log.d(TAG, "Key Data : " +  remoteMessage.getData().get("time").toString());
```

Wrap them in try catch to be sure

Answer (score 2):

The type of fun `getData()` is `Map<String, String>`. So you can fetch `data` object values like we usually fetch with `Map<String, String>`.

```
"data": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": "value4"
  }
```

then you have to fetch like this in kotlin

```
val data = remoteMessage.data
val key1 = data[key1]
val key2  = data[key2]// you can fetch like this
```

**For `getNotification()` type is `Notification` object**

```
val notification: Notification =  remoteMessage.notification
val message = notification.body
val title = notification.title // you can fetch by accessing Notification class member
```

Here are the details about the [Notification](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.Notification#public-method-summary) object

Comment: This was a very clear explanation. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        sendNotification(notification, data);
String urlparam=data.get("url_param").toString();
String urlparam=data.get("dp_name").toString();

"data": {
    "notification_id": 11,
    "title_url": "service_id=1;service_category=Installation;",
    "destination": "Category_page"
  }
```