# Make a custom data for parameter on firebase to call on push notification

Tags: php, android, firebase, push-notification, notifications

I researched from [Get value from RemoteMessage from FCM onMessageReceived method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38244332/get-value-from-remotemessage-from-fcm-onmessagereceived-method) for my problem but not helped

I want to create custom data in Firebase to call that data on my push notification. At least that data can call on onMessageReceived method.

My webservice

```
$msg = array
(
    'body'      => "$message",
    'title'     => "Approval System",
    'sound'     => 'default',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'

);
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $tokens,
    'questionTitle'     => "Test",
    'notification'      => $msg
    );


$headers = array(
    'Authorization:key = XXX',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);           
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
```

and my onMessageReceived method

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("DATA",messageBody);
Intent intent = new Intent(FirebaseMessage.this, ApprovalSystemActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
);

Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notif)
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.notif))
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText(messageBody))
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentTitle("Approval System")
        .setContentText(messageBody)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

how to i can call "questionTitle" on $fields array to java android ?
sorry for my question if cannot understand

谢谢

Comment: Post a sample JSON that you receive in device

Comment: I received data with remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()

Comment: I meant the json that you send from the server. Post that.

Comment: i am not send any json from server
i am just get data from FirebaseService without any data on my webservice
sorry if i am not understand

Comment: You are sending a json from server. Please do "echo json_encode($fields)" and paste it in your question

Comment: {"registration_ids":["dTlWTEzmJZk:APA91bF2COvY_WPcybE6okJv2a9qUkEUieDOP6q_Q204q1JMz-l2Un49M5cPg4WzE5ODTFyU_82Sz5lvR2zGO6Al_51lY1AyfEuw890jZ9YZ5pWn8kUjClAEwNjxBZ8eELQABRndhQom"],"questionTitle":"Test","notification":{"body":"xoa","title":"Approval System","sound":"default","vibrate":1,"largeIcon":"large_icon","smallIcon":"small_icon"}}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to change your JSON structure. Put the "questionTitle" field inside a "data" object

```
{
  "registration_ids": [
    "dTlWTEzmJZk:APA91bF2COvY_WPcybE6okJv2a‌​9qUkEUieDOP6q_Q204q1‌​JMz-l2Un49M5cPg4WzE5‌​ODTFyU_82Sz5lvR2zGO6‌​Al_51lY1AyfEuw890jZ9‌​YZ5pWn8kUjClAEwNjxBZ‌​8eELQABRndhQom"
  ],
  ‌​"notification": {
    "bod‌​y": "xoa",
    "title": "Ap‌​proval System",
    "sound": "default",
    "vibrate": 1,
    "largeIcon": "large_ico‌​n",
    "smallIcon": "smal‌​l_icon"
  },
  "data": {
    "qu‌​estionTitle": "Test"
  }
}
```

To make this JSON modify your php to:

```
$msg = array
 (
    'body'      => "$message",
    'title'     => "Approval System",
    'sound'     => 'default',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'

);

$dat = array
(
    'questionTitle'     => "Test"
);

$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $tokens,
    'notification'      => $msg,
    'data'       => $dat
);
```

And then in your Service class get it by

```
String questionTitle = remoteMessage.getData().get("questionTitle");
```

Comment: $fields = array
   (
    'registration_ids'  => array($registration_ids),
    'questionTitle'  => "Test",
    'notification'  => $msg
   );
how to change to that structure ?
I think to call service by your way but i am not change my JSON Structure because i am not understand your JSON Structure
Sorry I am newbie

Answer (score 0):

```
String questionTitle = remoteMessage.getData().get("questionTitle");
```

you may get it in class that is extending FirebaseMessagingService.